# How to close the pop up message box using Playwright?

Tags: javascript, node.js, playwright, javascript-debugger

I just learned Playwright API and I'm trying to write an automation test. The test is about logging into the bank account and do something with it. All my scripts worked until I've entered into the bank website where there's a message box popping out & I couldn't get rid of it by using "page.click()" method to simply click on the close button.

Here's how I do it from the loggin state until where I got stucked.

```
await page.goto("<bank_website_url>");
await page.fill("#username", <bank_username>);
await page.click('input:has-text("Login")');
await page.fill('#password', <bank_password>);
await page.click('input:has-text("Login")');
```

After entering the username & password, I'm now being directed into the bank website, and there's a message box showing up. What I want to do here is again using the "await page.click()" method to select the "close button" on the pop-up and close it but it doesn't work.

I'm sorry if my statement is not clear. Hope there's someone who can tell me what the potential issues/mistakes might be. Thank you!

Comment: `What I want to do here is again using the "await page.click()" method ... it but it doesn't work` Please show in the code *how* you're trying to do it.

Comment: Is the popup a web page dialog (e.g., `alert()`, `confirm()`, `prompt()`) or custom overlayed dialog? You're code looks right.

Answer (score 0):

By default, dialogs are auto-dismissed by Playwright, so you don't have to handle them. However, you can register a dialog handler before the action that triggers the dialog to accept or decline it.

```js
page.on('dialog', dialog => dialog.accept());
await page.click('button'); // trigger the dialog
```

See document at https://playwright.dev/docs/dialogs